# Using boost variant with std::functions containing a bool input

Tags: c++, function, pointers, boost, variant

See the following code:

```
void stringPtrFunc(const std::string *s) {}
void boolFunc(const bool b) {}

int main() {
    boost::variant<std::function<void(const std::string *)>, std::function<void(const bool)>> myVariant;

    myVariant = &stringPtrFunc; // Compiles fine
    myVariant = &boolFunc; // Error
}
```

I'm getting an error about ambiguous overload. Seems like stringPtrFunc is convertable to boolFunc, but not vice versa. Why isn't there an exact match happening? Can I force the match?

Thanks,

Ryan

Comment: This code does _not_ compile - a typo.  My compiler reports:  "error: cannot declare ‘::main’ to be a global variable"

Comment: `myVariant = std::function<void(const bool)>(&boolFunc);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `&boolFunc` is not a `std::function` (of any type), it is a function pointer.  As such, it can be converted to any `std::function` that it is compatible with, but no one of them is any better than any other.  In particular, since any pointer type can be implicitly converted to bool, `&boolFunc` can convert to `std::function<void(T *)>` for any pointer type.

As a result, it matches equally well with either variant type.

To avoid this, you need to say explicitly which `std::function` you want:

```
myVariant = std::function<void(const bool)>(&boolFunc);
```